# Invoke-wmimethod win32_process

Tags: powershell-2.0, invoke, powershell-4.0

Background: I am creating a script to send out a message to everyone in my Domain. I was able to complete this using Invoke-WMImethod and MSG.exe. However, my supervisor wants a more customizable message to be sent. Like changing Color, font size, font style...etc. Which i have created using PowerShell.

Script:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $Computer -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList {"C:\x\x\x\Powershell.exe -File `"\\Server\Share\Folder\Script.ps1`""}
```

When i run this script against my Computer it works perfectly. However, when i attempt to run it on a remote computer it fails. 
I don't understand why.

It's the same exact script that i used with MSG.exe, which worked, but it still doesn't work with a powershell script.

I attempted to copy the script to the remote computers 'C:\' and run it from that file path but it still didn't work.

I've verified the file path to Powershell.exe is the same as the script and that the remote workstation can access the .PS1 Script.

However, the script does run and says it is successful with a Return Value of 0. Example:

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ProcessId        : 8748
ReturnValue      : 0

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion would be to check for the versions on both the machines. The CmdLet you using may not be working on the previous version.

I again have a suggestion to make, you can use the below command to get your work done, if you have powershell Version 3 or above.

```
$Outputreport = "Test message to send data using port 443"
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post https://hostnamedotcom/cgi-bin/dir-path/$hostname-filename -Body $Outputreport
```

Comment: I tested that out from a PS v 2.0 to PS v 5.1 and it worked so it's not the PS version.